# CentOS 7 ipsec hardware rngd erorr

Tags: ipsec, openswan

```
ipsec verify
```

> Hardware RNG detected, testing if used properly
>   [FAILED]
>
> Hardware RNG is present but 'rngd' is not running.   No harware
>   random used!

Someone suggest to edit `/etc/sysconfig/rngd`, add following line

```
EXTRAOPTIONS="-r /dev/urandom"
```

Which does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the rngd-tools installed by the yum would not read the environment file `/etc/sysconfig/rngd`.

open `/usr/lib/systemd/system/rngd.service`, add `-r /dev/urandom` to the `ExecStart`.

`ExecStart=/sbin/rngd -f -r /dev/urandom`